# How to add timestamp to tag src in index.html using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-cache

I am using angular 1 to develop an application
I want to add a argument to my scripts, so the browser detecte a change and load them for second time.
Because of the cache, changes are not token in consideration by the browser

Here is my index file:

```
<html lang="fr" ng-app="app" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.flatly.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_sejour.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/jquery.1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/libs/angular/1.3.12/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular/1.3.12/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular/1.3.12/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular/1.3.12/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

    <script src="app/sejour/prestation/prestation.js></script>

    <script src="app/sejour/fournisseur/fournisseur.js?v=1.0.4"></script>
    <script src="app/sejour/sejour/sejour.js?v=1.0.4"></script>
    <script src="app/sejour/sejour/sejour_edit.js?v=1.0.4"></script>
    <script src="app/services/fournisseur_service.js?v=1.0.4"></script>
    </head>
```

For the last 4 lines, i want to change "1.0.4" by a dynamic variable,
I don't want to right it manually

If u can see, there are no controller added in this step, because it is the first step to load Angular and its features

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Make your script tags have no src and have the class `dynScr`, then put this in your head.

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll(".dynScr")[0].src="app/sejour/fournisseur/fournisseur.js?v="+(new Date()).getTime();
document.querySelectorAll(".dynScr")[1].src="app/sejour/sejour/sejour.js?v="+(new Date()).getTime();
document.querySelectorAll(".dynScr")[2].src="app/sejour/sejour/sejour_edit.js?v="+(new Date()).getTime();
document.querySelectorAll(".dynScr")[3].src="app/services/fournisseur_service.js?v="+(new Date()).getTime();
</script>
```